# jQuery dataTables hide Show Entries text but show the dropdown list

Tags: datatables

jQuery dataTables hide "Show Entries" text but show the dropdown list in right side of page.

```js
$('#myTable_reports_view').DataTable({
   "aoColumnDefs": [
       {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [2,3,4,5,7]}
   ],
   "bFilter": false,
   "bInfo": false,
   "bLengthChange": true
});
```

I am adding this code. The problem is "Show DDL entries" is getting hide but I want to hide the text part only, not the dropdown list.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, hiding the lengthmenu hides the text *and* the lengthmenu. If you just want to get rid of the "*Show XX entries*" text, then simply alter the language settings for that particular element. The default settings is :

```js
"oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries"
}
```

reset that in your initialization :

```js
$('#myTable_reports_view').DataTable({
   "bFilter": false,
   "bInfo": false,
   "bLengthChange": true,
   oLanguage: {
       sLengthMenu: "_MENU_",
    }
});
```

Now you will only have the dropdown, not the prefix / suffixes. Here is an extracted list of all `oLanguage` defaults :

```js
"oLanguage": {
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
        "sSortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
    },
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "First",
        "sLast": "Last",
        "sNext": "Next",
        "sPrevious": "Previous"
    },
    "sEmptyTable": "No data available in table",
    "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sDecimal": "",
    "sThousands": ",",
    "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Loading...",
    "sProcessing": "Processing...",
    "sSearch": "Search:",
    "sSearchPlaceholder": "",
    "sUrl": "",
    "sZeroRecords": "No matching records found"
 }
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for:  `oLanguage: {
       sLengthMenu: "_MENU_",
    }`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to remove Data Table `showing entries`

```js
    $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
       "bInfo" : false
    });
```